# What is the best way to show power point documents on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm developing iPad app that need to show PPT files. I tried to show PPT file from 
web server which showed as continuous page, instead of this, need to show like slides, slide show futures..etc

If PPT is not supported in iPad what formats can we convert that to showcase in the iPad application.